# How to report exception to Android developer console?

Tags: java, android, developer-console

As I discussed in another post ([Restore stack trace from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908730/restore-stack-trace-from-string)) I restore an exception from a database. I want to report this exception to the Android developer console - but how can I do this?

When the following code is executed, the user is requested to send the exception to the console (the dialog I want to see):

```
String test = null;
int lenght = test.length;
```

If I add "throw new Exception();", I always have to add "throws Exception" to the method signature, so it will never end up to report it to the developer console.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The null pointer exception (from your example) is an unchecked exception (exceptions which don't require catching or updates to method signature). You can always throw a runtime exception (the unchecked superclass) if you want: `throw new RuntimeException("myerror")`. Look into unchecked exceptions for more info. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763869/2711811.  Ofcourse this would terminate your app - and this appears to be what you want to force the dev console report?  You can also extend the RuntimeException with your custom unchecked exception.

Comment: This was exactly I was looking for - thank you very much!!! My question is solved!